# Visual Studio working directory

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, dll

It looks like there are similar question to mine, but they have workarounds that I would rather avoid.

I have a bin folder in my project that contains all the dynamic libraries needed to run the program.

So to let the program find the dll, I have set the Working Directory in

```
Project Property Pages -> All Configurations 
-> Configuration Properties -> Debugging -> Working Directory
```

Unfortunately I am greated with an error that the libary has not been found. It looks like VS does not change the working directory before running the program.

Did I miss something or is this a known bug without a fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't have VS currently available but I usually add all shared libraries to my `PATH` variable. Just add as environment variable

[image: Project settings for environment variables]

I know it's not a direct answer to your question but I hope it helps anyway

Comment: That would make a clutter in my PATH, the libs are only needed for the project

Comment: You can set the path for one specific project - look in the project settings where you also set the working directory

Comment: Ok, that worked, will wait a few more hours to see if anybody else has a better solution, if not I will mark this as accepted answer

Comment: Glad it helped. Anyway - I prefer that method because you can add multiple directories and keep your third-party libraries separated. Just my two cents :)